# Scrum: How much can the Product Owner shake up the Product Backlog?

Tags: scrum

For the last 3 sprints or so, I've observed our Product Owner suddenly shoving new stories -- stories not previously in the Product Backlog -- at the top of the Product Backlog.

Because of this, the existing items in the backlog never get worked on.  New stories continuously take over the helm and make into our Sprint Backlog.

My question is - how much can the Product Owner really shake up the Product Backlog?  Is it really fair game to ignore what's already in the backlog and keep on shoving new stories at the top?

I've tried to argue that this is hogwash, but I often hear counter-arguments such as "adapting to frequently changing business needs," "we're moving so fast - we're super agile" and I don't know what to say to those arguments, although I feel it is not how Scrum was meant to be.

EDIT:
I understand that the product owner owns the product backlog.  What I am observing at my team though, is that the PO constantly puts new items at the top of the backlog, ignoring the existing backlog items completely.

For instance, say we're building a car and PO creates 10 stories to make it happen.  We decide to take on 3 stories in our sprint backlog - thus 7 stories still remain in the product backlog.  Everything is good so far.

At the next sprint planning, however, the PO now claims that we need to build a baseball bat and creates 5 stories around that - which are then placed at the top of our backlog (i.e. highest priority); nevermind those car stories we already had in the backlog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the PO is just doing their job. It is their job to know the needs of the customer, and to balance those with the needs of the business. They are the ones that decide what the company will ultimately sell. If they switch from automobiles to baseball bats, presumably that's because they've decided bats are more important. If they *are* more important, why do you want to continue to build an automobile?

If the team is bothered by this, *talk to the PO* and tell them your concerns. Again, they are just doing their job, but they should know the effect this churn has on the development team. It's hard to focus on a product when you're constantly switching products back and forth.

Comment: "If they are more important, why do you want to continue to build an automobile?" - you certainly don't.  But I also feel that there's something wrong when we're building a different product each sprint, without finishing any of them.  It tells me that proper due diligence is not performed by the PO to really understand what the customer wants, and I'd be curious to know how Scrum as a framework handles that if at all.

Comment: @user226825: you could be right - you might just have an incompetent PO. That's not the fault of scrum, or of your development team.

Comment: the product backlog should be known to the devs. if there are only new stories and no known stories on the day of planning game, dev team had no time to think about the stories up front. that's bad. a better way is to have the team know about backlog items and move them nearer the top if they become more clearer and more ready to be put into a sprint. if PO only adds new stories on the day of planning game, he may have no strategic vision for the product and reacts to short-term requirements. that's operative but not strategic.

Comment: @mhaller: Absolutely, the backlog should be available to the whole team pretty much all the time.

Answer (score 6):

```
> how much can the Product Owner really shake up the Product Backlog?
```

It is the job of the Product Owner to "shake up the Product Backlog".

In Scrum it is the job of the [product owner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29#Roles) to  rank and prioritize the features in the [Product_Backlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29#Product_Backlog).

**product owner and team agree** what to implement in the next sprint and put these features into the [Sprint_Backlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29#Sprint_Backlog)

You as a developer have to argue if you need technical features in the sprint log that the product owner doesn't see.

Comment: It's not so much that the technical features are missing.  It's more like, new stories show up out of nowhere for the devs to take on for the next sprint.  Basically we have no backlog; whatever PO comes up with on the Sprint Planning day is what we'll work on for the next sprint.

Answer (score 6):

In traditional Scrum, the Product Owner is the person who owns the Product Backlog. This person is responsible for adding or removing stories as appropriate and ensuring that the list is prioritized based on the needs of the stakeholders. However, the Development Team is responsible for ensuring that the Product Backlog Items that are added are understood and good enough (complete, clear, testable, feasible, etc) to be estimated and delivered when they come up in a future sprint.

From your perspective on the development team, you shouldn't be relying on the product backlog. All of your actions - your requirements elaboration, architecture and design, implementation, and testing should be fully based on the Sprint Backlog. This is what gets fixed for a particular Sprint and changes to the Sprint Backlog should be minimized.

Remember that the Product Owner is the voice of the stakeholder for the development team. They are the ones who understand what the business need for the system is and what capabilities or features would have the most impact.

Warning signs to look out for would be the Product Owner attempting to change the Sprint Backlog or having a Product Owner that is out of touch with the needs of the business or user base.

Comment: I think this nails it.

Comment: I agree that the devs should focus on the Sprint Backlog; however we aren't blind. When the PO constantly pushes new items as our 'highest priority' it is only natural for the devs to question, "what happened to those items remaining in the Product Backlog that you said were important last time around?" In short, I am starting to realize that our team really doesn't have a Product Backlog - whatever comes to PO's mind will become the "Product Backlog" for the next sprint.

Answer (score 5):

> how much can the Product Owner really shake up the Product Backlog?

As much as he likes.
It is the "Product Owners" job to represent the user and get them what they want.

> Is it really fair game to ignore what's already in the backlog and keep on shoving new stories at the top?

Sure is.
If the old stories are no longer relevant to the user why build them. You only want to build what is important to the user. But be careful. A story is supposed to be a user action. You should be able to describe a story in terms of an action a user does (no technical details).

> I've tried to argue that this is hogwash

It is the job of the "Scrum Master" to protect the developers from flippant change.
It is the job of the "Scrum Master" to pick what makes it into the sprint and protect the developers from the "Product Owner" and make sure the technical part of the project work. This means he should be picking items to form the architecture first. He should try and deliver some user stories but the ones that make sense (trying to respect the Product Owners priority but he does not need to stick to it 100% if that does not make technological sense).

> Note: As pointed out below my definition of "Scrum Master" here may not be fully standard. I was simply using it to point out that it is **not the Job** of the PO to pick tasks for the scrum backlog as this is a technical in nature (and the PO being a chicken has no voice in the sprint planning). It is the job of the team to pick what goes in the sprint backlog as they are technically inclined and understand how components will interact. They will be heavily influenced by the priority in the product backlog but that is not there only consideration they use when making technical decisions. My use of the term "Scrum Master" is heavily influenced by my experience where the "Scrum Master" is usually the technical or team lead (usually a senior dev with the clout/fortitude to stand up to management who tend to be pushy when they can get away with it) this of course is not required by scrum.

-

> but I often hear counter-arguments such as "adapting to frequently changing business needs," "we're moving so fast - we're super agile" and I don't know what to say to those arguments,

These are good arguments. But make sure

1. You are talking about true stories
2. Your architecture takes priority over user interface

> although I feel it is not how Scrum was meant to be.

Scrum is meant to allow you to react quickly.
But during a sprint there should be no change to the sprint backlog. And make sure your sprints are of reasonable length: 3 to 4 weeks. That should give you a chance to finish a reasonable small story or build the foundation for a large story.

Comment: In our situation, the old stories still have values and remain in our backlog.  However, right before our Sprint Planning the PO comes up with new stories and they are then placed at the top of the Product Backlog.

Comment: "It is the job of the "Scrum Master" to protect the developers from flippant change."  Sure, but what does SM do when PO says that the new stories are indeed what the business needs and must be taken care of in the upcoming sprint?

Comment: @user226825: So. Since you have not done any work on jobs in the product backlog what does it matter. You do the most important story's that the PO wants (making sure architecture is not impacted). The problem with developers is they want to develop "cool" stories. The job of the PO is to make sure the work you do is relevant to the people that use the software. The job of the SM is to make sure the architecture is not compromised by the PO, make sure the developers do appropriate jobs.

Comment: I'm not saying that we want to work on the cool stories.  Let me illustrate - Let's say we're building a car and PO creates 10 stories in the Product Backlog and we do 3 stories in the sprint.  The next sprint, the PO says "hey guys, we actually have to make a bicycle instead and here are the 5 stories around that; they're going to the top of the backlog for the next sprint; the car is a nice-to-have but not our top priority anymore."

Comment: @user226825: Once you have built the bike you can go back to building the car. But what is the point in building a car when the user wants a bike. That is why you have demos. So the user can see what you have done and tell you that you are on the wrong track and building a car when he only wants a bike.

Comment: "Once you have built the bike you can go back to building the car." Right, except that for the next sprint the bike becomes a space shuttle whose stories take over the top of backlog.  It's always like this - some new thing just pops up and becomes our 'top priority' even before we finish building the car or the bike.

Comment: @user226825: Yes but in sprint one you built wheels and transmission. In Sprint 2 you built steering in sprint three you will build thrusters. Your examples are too hypothetical to really discuss further. But yes the PO gets to order the product backlog.

Comment: I wish if they were related like a bike and a car, and it is my fault for using vehicles as an example.  The PO usually stuffs completely unrelated items, say a bike and a fridge.

Comment: @user226825: Read the definition of story. It is a description of a user performing a task not a thing.

Comment: I understand how stories are written.  The PO is creating user stories to build products in my oversimplified examples.  I'm not arguing about the format of stories; rather, the flapping nature of backlog managed by our PO.

Comment: I've never heard it described as the scrum master's job to pick what stories go into the sprint. Can you cite a reference for that? I thought it was the PO who decided what does in the sprint by prioritizing the backlog.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I totally agree with you. Maybe my wording just needs refining. Maybe more the teams job (rather than SM by himself) to pick what goes into the sprint during sprint planning (PM is not a pig (just a chicken) and gets no say at this point).

Comment: @BryanOakley: But note there are two backlogs. The product backlog is controlled by the PO and ordered appropriately. The sprint backlog which is owned by the SM (and/or team). The stuff that goes in the sprint backlog **should** be from the **top** of the product backlog **BUT** not all stories can be done without other architectural stories being implemented first. So the SM (and the devs) should make sure to pick architectural priorities first when the high priority stories depend on the architectural stories.

Comment: I've never heard of a sprint backlog being owned by a scrum master, either. They can help a team do some prioritization, but they don't actually do it themselves. The team is the unit responsible for delivery at the end of the sprint, so they decide the priority.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Yes. I agree. I think that is also what I said three comments above. I am using SM in this context as a short hand for the team as the SM is usually (but not required) the team lead (or a member of the development team that talks to the PO). But I agree with your point. I just think we are arguing over wording. The point being that the PO does not decide what is in the sprint as that is a technical discussion. **BUT** he does influence it heavily by the ordering of the backlog.

Comment: The scrum master shouldn't normally be the team lead -- that's not how scrum works. The scrum master role is designed as a distinct role separate from the construction team, someone who acts as a facilitator and coach. If you're going to base an answer on a non-standard definition of a standard scrum role, you should put that in your answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I think you like playing with words: To me `facilitator and coach` sounds exactly like a lead. But sure I can see that he does not need to be part of the team.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Added a paragraph.

Comment: The idea that anyone "picks tasks" for the sprint backlog is, based on my understanding and experience, incorrect. The sprint backlog is filled by taking the prioritized tasks from the product backlog (as ordered by PO) and the velocity from the previous sprint. The highest priority task is taken and moved into the sprint backlog until the size of the sprint backlog is equal to the velocity of the last sprint. The ScrumMaster doesn't have nearly as much active responsibility as you describe - the Scrum Master is only there to remove roadblocks that slow down or stop work from progressing.

Comment: Personally, I think you are still a little off base. The modern definition of a product owner is more toward being a pig than a chicken. For example, see [Building a better Product Owner](http://www.scrumalliance.org/resources/357) and [The dirtiest pig in scrum - the Product Owner](http://agilechange.wordpress.com/2009/04/18/the-dirtiest-pig-in-scrum-the-product-owner/) as well as [the section on scrum roles on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)#Roles)

Comment: @ThomasOwens: In a perfect world yes. But in reality no. There are always stories that **NEED** doing that the product owner does not rate as important (as they are not customer facing). But in reality they need to be done because architectural they will be in a mess if you don't do them.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: I agree with your point on SM (see my note above in the article); And in a **perfect world** I would also agree on how the sprint backlog is filled, but in reality no. There are always stories that NEED doing that the product owner does not rate as important (as they are not customer facing). But in reality they need to be done because architectural they will be in a mess if you don't do them.

Comment: @BryanOakley: If I had product owners that were technically competent (or when they gain enough experience to understand the nuances of a large system) then I can see the role being extended in that direction. But until that point I can not see them directing architectural choices that would be discussed with the developers while working out tasks.

Comment: @LokiAstari Every user story in the product backlog should be user facing functionality. I don't know what you mean by the architecture being a mess if you don't do them. If a feature is more important to the customer, you implement it sooner. If that means you need to incur technical debt, then you incur that technical debt and manage that risk by budgeting refactoring in later, usually by giving user stories a greater number of story points to account for refactoring, updating tests, and executing more regression tests.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. Your answer seems to be geared more toward your personal experience than toward how scrum is supposed to work. That's cool, and people may find your answer useful, but I think as it's written it may give a wrong impression to those who are trying to understand how scrum should work.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: Yep. All stories are user stories. But not all users are customers. Not all stories can be done without infrastructure. Sure if you are writing a small web app or a desktop application then yes I am sure you can get away with that. In reality no. If you build big software it takes more though on the architecture. I have several stories at the top of the backlog that can not even be attempted (probably for a year) as we need underlying stories to work first. We have mocjed out the UI so that we can show what it looks like but real interaction is not going to work.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I think you are talking about ideals that we should strive for while I am describing the reality of scrum in the real world.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: The first stories we did on this project were not in the top 100 of the product backlog. The product owner did not rate it as important at all. But the whole team insisted that it must be done first. 1) Story: Allow a developer/tester to build any part of the project on their machine/Test environment/Production using the same set of tools/commands /*long description about tools*/ 2) Story: Allow a developer to checks in code, so that it is automatically validated against unit tests and full system build by scheduled and validated against test data. /* Lots more detail*/.

Comment: Those aren't user stories at all. That's infrastructure setup that should have been done in what I've always heard called "Sprint 0" or as a Spike facilitate the development stories. If you aren't working on stories that the PO (and therefore the customer or user) has prioritized, you are doing it very wrong.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: But you did them first. Its a sprint and a story. We work on stories that will facilitate us doing the top priority story. Its not that we pick random stories we want to do, we work closely with the PO. But sometimes stories are just not doable at the current time; the architecture is not there to support it. There is not point in doing a story that can not succeed yet. Can't be that wrong. We deliver at the end of each sprint. We move forward rapidly and the software is well tested and maintainable with few bugs and neither our PO or customer are upset.

Comment: @LokiAstari: another way of looking at your problem is that the "stories" for tools and infrastructure aren't stories at all. Instead, they are tasks that need to be completed in order to complete the first story on the backlog. If the PO says "The most important story is X", your team simply needs to say "Ok, to complete X, we'll need a task to set up a build environment. We'll also need a task to set up SCM, and to run unit tests". Bottom line is, the team gets to decide how to fully implement the PO's top priority story, even if that means there are a bunch of one time setup tasks.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Sure we could do that. If we did that we would have several sprints were we completed no stories and only did tasks (architecture).You seem to stuck in the mind set that the "customer" is the only user(and thus the only person that gets stories). I disagree with that concept. To me there are many types of user. The customer is the most important one but I have to serve all of them. I can only amass so much technical debt (As Thomas puts it) before it becomes unmaintainable and costs the company more than we make from the product so the customer is not the only user I worry about.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I think you are misinterpreting my statements. You seem to have a PO that is largely ignorant of the need for some improvements to your infrastructure. My suggestion for working around this situation is to simply make this work part of the first user story, if the PO insists that the first story is customer-centric. The team is responsible for telling the PO what it will take to complete that story. If "what it will take" includes setting up a testing infrastructure or an SCM tool or bug tracker or whatever, the PO has to accept that or be willing to negotiate.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Our service is currently running on AWS when they shut down machines we create maintenance stories. We currently have $100,000 per month bill for storage so we have a story to reduce storage costs. We had a bug that has been fixed but we noticed some strange data so we have Data Quality story. We have a story to fix an issue with logging as this affects customer charging. None of these are important to the customer. We could just call them random tasks, but we count them as stories as they affect our velocity. Some of these will out way "Customer" stories and get into the sprint.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I think your view on user is too limited. In real life we have competing priorities. The customer is always at the forefront of our thoughts. But we have other architectural concerns that have other users (Accounts/Management.etc) to make sure we build a product that is maintainable.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I'm not talking about _my_ view. You're the one with a PO that seems to see everything only through the customers eyes. Again, my point is, if _your_ PO doesn't understand the technical debt, one way to work with _your_ PO is to say that for the first user story you're going to have to tackle some infrastructure changes. Personally I'm well aware of these types of stories because I'm a PO myself. My team doesn't have this problem. The right long term solution is to better educate your PO about the technical demands of software development.

Comment: re: "None of these are important to the customer.". I disagree -- all of those are important to the customer. If your storage costs go up, you'll end up passing that on to the customer, won't you? And surely your customer cares about software quality. And if your logging is buggy you might end up charging the customer incorrectly, and surely they care about that. If you want to count those as stories, that's the smart thing to do. It sounds, however, like _your_ PO doesn't seem them as stories. You need to educate your PO, or find a way to work within their limited vision.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Thanks for helping me walking through that. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers here and I do agree that it is the PO's job to do that as he/she has to determine the best possible ROI for the product.  He/she would be doing the wrong thing by building less valuable PBI's.

However there are some fundamental rules.

- The PO cannot change the current sprint by moving items in and out at whim.
- When the PO adds a new item,  the team has needs to estimate it and the PO needs to respect that estimate
- The PO is then responsible for managing time, budget and scope (the magic triangle).  i.e. if they add new items they have to come up with more budget or remove an equivalent lower valued item.
- The PO is accountable to make sure the items have enough detail in them that the team can pick 1up in sprint planning.  It should have enough information that the team can ask minor clarification questions.   This is often a dysfunction in many teams where a long time is spent discussing what the requirement is, instead of minor clarifications.
- The PO in grooming sessions should consult with the team and heed their advise on any potential challenges with new requirements, impacts or dependencies.  This should help him/her order or make better decisions.

**Is it the teams accountability and responsibility of defining what gets built or that of how it should get built?**  The bottom line is its not the teams decision or risk to take and the team should focus on delivery of quality items regardless of what they are.

Finally,  use retrospectives to thrash out any concerns you may have

Comment: Our team nails all the items.  The only problem is, the contents of 'Product Backlog' flips so much from one sprint to another, that there is no continuity in our work.  Hence I tried to get a sense of how much freedom PO has in modifying the Product Backlog.  If the answer is as much as he/she likes, then it is Scrum's limitation to not being able to prevent the situation we're in from happening.

Comment: Scrum is all about _encouraging_ this situation to happen. If you're not building what the customer wants, the PO is obligated to change the backlog to deliver what the customer wants. Scrum is about optimizing for the customer, not for the development team.

Comment: @BryanOakley I agree if the PO is doing proper due diligence to understand customer wants.  The frequency with which we switch products back and forth makes it harder to believe that that is the case, though.  Does Scrum offer some guidance on this front?

Comment: @user226825: if the backlog is changing frequently, that might be a sign that the PO might be doing something wrong. There's not a lot scrum has to say with respect to people who can't do their job. I guess the first step is to figure out if your PO is incompetent, or if he/she has good reasons for doing what they do. Answer that question by having an open conversation with your PO.

Comment: user226825, it does sound like the frequent change is impacting the team.  Have a retrospective with the PO and thrash out concerns and try reach a balance where the PO has freedom to change but giving enough similar context to the team.   As this is a self-organising team,  ask the team how they can adapt to this situation and make it work.  I recommend trying to align more with PO changes whereby things can be complex and unpredictable but not to the level where the PO is clueless.  See if the PO has challenges whereby he/she is getting bad info and see what the team can do to help.